# Proof that a formula $\theta$ is valid if and only if $\forall x \theta$ is valid

Tags: logic

I need to prove for first-order logic that $\vDash\theta$ if and only if $\vDash\forall x \theta$. The proof for the forward direction seems simple enough:

Suppose $\theta$ is valid. Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be an arbitrary structure and let $s:V\to |\mathfrak{A}|$ be an arbitrary function assigning values of the universe of $\mathfrak{A}$ to variables. Then we know by assumption that $\vDash_\mathfrak{A}\theta[s]$.

But since $s$ is arbitrary, it follows that $\vDash_\mathfrak{A}\theta[s(x|c)]$, for all $c\in|\mathfrak{A}$. But this means that $\vDash_\mathfrak{A}\forall x\theta[s]$. Since $\mathfrak{A}$ and the function assigning elements of the structure to variables are arbitrary, it follows that $\vDash\forall x\theta$.

Now we have to show that if $\vDash\forall x\theta$, then $\vDash\theta$, and this is where I'm stuck. I understand why it makes sense that this should be true, I'm just having a hard time writing it rigorously. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument you already have works equaly well in reverse:

You know that $\vDash_{\mathfrak A} \theta[s(x|c)]$ for all $\mathfrak A$, $s$ and $c$. You want to prove  $\vDash_{\mathfrak A} \theta[s]$.

Very well, then just take $c=s(x)$ in your assumption ...