# Show $\Phi$ is true in a model $M$ if and only if ($\forall x$)$\Phi$ is true in $M$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have to proof that
$\Phi$  is true in a model $M$ if and only if ($\forall x$)$\Phi$ is true in $M$.

I read the chapter in my textbook several times and already found this question [Proof that a formula $\theta$ is valid if and only if $\forall x \theta$ is valid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196345/proof-that-a-formula-theta-is-valid-if-and-only-if-forall-x-theta-is-vali)

But i did not understand this.
I guess what i have to proof is, that $\Phi$ in a model is only true if $\Phi$ is true for all possible values of all variables in $\Phi$

I would be very thankful if someone can show me how to proof this.
Thank you!

Edit: 
A formula $\Phi$ of L(R, F, C) is true in the model $M$ = (D, I) for L(R, F, C)
provided, $\Phi^{I,A}$ = t for all assignments A. A formula $\Phi$ is valid if $\Phi$ is
true in all models for the language. A set S of formulas is satisfiable in
M = (D, I), provided there is some assignment A (called a satisfying
assignment) such that $\Phi^{I,A}$ = t for all $\Phi$     $\in$ S. S is satisfiable if it is
satisfiable in some model.

Comment: What is your definition of $\Phi$ being true in a model $M$?

Comment: I added this definition in the question above. Thank you!

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun my textbook is First order logic and automated theorem proving by Melvin Fitting

Comment: Quite a bit of this notation is nonstandard. I assume that $(D, I)$ means we have a domain $D$ and interpretation $I$? And then $\Phi^{I, A}$ means we interpret $\Phi$ according to $I$ and $A$ are elements of $D$ that are used to substitute for the free variables in $\Phi$? This is an exercise in just writing out definitions and seeing that they mean the same thing. So it should help to write out all the definitions for yourself (maybe do it here).

Comment: Yes, $M$ = ($D$, $I$) means, that $D$ is the Domain of the Model $M$ and $I$ is a mapping called interpration. According to $\Phi^{I,A}$ yes, $A$ is an assignment in the model $M$ and it`s used to substitute free variables

Comment: Comapre your def above with clause 4 page 106, regarding $\forall$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA i don't have a clause 4 on page 106, but i scrolled down a little bit and found definition  5.1.6 with clause 4: The free-variable occurrences in (∀x)A and ($\exists$ x)A are the freevariable occurrences in A, except for occurrences of x. 
Do you mean this?

Comment: Because than maybe this is the "solution"?
 $\Phi$ can only be true for $(\forall x) \Phi$ because according to clause 4, any free variables in $(\forall x) \Phi$ are also free variables in  $\Phi$ and need to be bound?

Comment: I'm referring to 5.3.5 and 5.3.6 (in my edition).

Comment: We have that $\Phi$ is *true* in M iff $\Phi^{I,A}= \text t$ for all assign. $A$. Thus, if $\Phi$ is true in $M$, and $A$ is an assign., we have that $\Phi^{I,B}= \text t$ for all assign. $B$ that are $x$-variant of $A$. Thus $[(\forall x)\Phi]^{I,A}=\text t$. But this olds for every $A$.

Comment: And if there is an validation  $\Phi^{I,B}$=t but $[(\forall x) \Phi]^{I,A} = f$ this would be false? If this is right i think i understood it..

Comment: Or in other words: if there is a validation of $[(\forall x) \Phi]^{I,A} = false$ the equivalent x-variant $B$ $\Phi^{I,B}$ is also $f$.

Comment: Try to supplement the formal def with examples... Let $\Phi$ is $(x \ge 0)$. Let $M$ the usual structure $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers and let the assign $A$ the function that $A(x)=1$. Clearly we have that $\Phi^A=\text t$ because $1 \ge 0$.

Comment: What about $B$ an $x$-variant of $A$ ? For example, a $B$ such that $B(x)=2$ will do and we have that $\Phi^B=\text t$. But this will be for **every** $x$-variant, because for every $n \in \mathbb 
 N$ we have $(n \ge 0)$. This means that $[(\forall x) \Phi]^A= \text t$.

Comment: This, in a nutshell, the machinery explained in the post you have linked above...

Comment: Thank you very much Mauro, you helped me alot!